# How do I deploy spring boot app alongside angular app

Tags: angular, spring-boot, web, deployment

I want to use the same port for both my Spring Boot and Angular apps for my project , so I built my Angular project and copied dist files and placed them in `src/resources/static` in spring boot and than packed my Spring Boot project in `jar` but http://localhost:8080/ returns `401` error.

I thought it's gonna automatically open my `index.html` but it didn't...

Comment: A 401 is a security authentication error. What does your security config look like? Probably need more                 .antMatchers(resources).permitAll()